# What is R.id.container?

Tags: android

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
}
```

1. What does this code exactly do?
2. R.id.container is declared both in the activity_detail.xml which is associated with the class of the above code, and activity_main.xml. How does the code know which R.id.container it is referring to?

Answer (score 2):

Normally you add a layout to your activity in the onCreate method. That's how the code knows which container is referred.

Comment: What does container mean in Android?

Comment: Container ist just an ID. In your layout xml there will be some View or Layout having `android:id="@+id/container"`. For that, the constant  R.id.container is created and via that, you can access to that View or Layout from code.

Answer (score 1):

It simply adds a `Fragment` to the 'container' you've declared in your xml layout. Since you've added a layout in e.g. `onCreate()` the compiler knows which layout is the correct one.

Add: 'container' is just a name or an id. Post your xml ...